# CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage not showing image

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I'm having issues using `CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage` with a central image.

*I'm pretty sure* that at one point the image I choose was showing up within the progress ring, but after relauncing a few times, the image disappeared. Oddly, when I've tried to use it in `CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallSquare` and `CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallFlat` the image shows up just fine. 
For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
let smallRing = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()  
smallRing.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Complication/Utilitarian")!)  
smallRing.ringStyle = .Closed  
smallRing.fillFraction = 5 / 9  
handler(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: NSDate(), complicationTemplate: smallRing))
```

A few more details:

- Not working on device or simulator.
- My image is 14pt (28px), I have tried with PDF (single vector) and PNGs (non-interlaced).
- Works as expected with any `CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmall`* that accepts images except `CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage`.
- Have tried using a Complication Image Set, just an image in the Catalog both Apple Watch and Universal...
- Have tried not setting other properties on `CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage`.
- Crashes on targetting the incorrect image name, so I know it's loading the image when the name is accurate.
- Tried with tint color and just changing around the image's default color to see if that's it. Nope. Would think it's the image if it wasn't working in other Templates!

I have to be doing something unusual though.

Comment: Also tried it in a new application with the same result - a ring without an image. Is this just a bug in ClockKit? Reporting to Radar, anyway.

Comment: I'm seeing the same, did you ever figure out a fix?

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the newest iOS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug with WatchOS 2.2.1!

Thankfully fixed in 2.2.2!